# Centering the content of a drop down

Tags: html, css

I have a drop down list that appears when hovering over a nav item. I want each a tag within the drop down to be centered vertically in the drop down. I have turned the list items red to help me understand their positions.
Here is my html

```css
      .navDropList .navDropItem{
        margin-top: 10px;
        background-color: red;
        width: 100%;
        list-style: none;
    }
    
    
    .navDropList{
        padding-top: 40px;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
    
        background-color:#414141;
    }
    
    .navDropList ul{
        margin-bottom: 15%;
    }
    
    .navList .navTag:hover .navDropList{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
    
    .navDropList .dropTag{
        font-size: 20px;
        color:#d3d3d3;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    }
    
    .navList .navListItem:hover .navDropList{
        display: block;
    }
    
    .navDropList .dropTag:hover{
        font-weight: 900;
    }
```

```html
<nav>
            <ul class= "navList">
                <li class=navListItem><a class="navTag current" 
        href="nehemiahUniversity.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class=navListItem><a class="navTag" href="courses.HTML" >Courses</a></li>
                <li class=navListItem><a class="navTag" href="training.html">Training Material</a>
                    <div class="navDropList">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="navDropItem"><a class="dropTag" 
    href="training.html#productionSection">Production</a></li>
                            <li class="navDropItem"><a class="dropTag" 
    href="training.html#warehouseSection">Warehouse</a></li>
                            <li class="navDropItem"><a class="dropTag" 
    href="training.html#qualitySection">Quality Control</a></li>
                            <li class="navDropItem"><a class="dropTag" 
    href="training.html#blendingSection">Blending</a></li>
                            <li class="navDropItem"><a class="dropTag" 
    href="training.html#officeSection">Office</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class=navListItem><a class="navTag" href="walkthrough.HTML">Walkthrough</a> 
        </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        </div>
      </header>
```

Here is what the drop down looks like [drop down list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c92Vq.png)

How do I get the text to be centered in the drop down?

Comment: It would help if you formatted your code with a snippet

Comment: Are you sure you mean vertically centered?

Comment: okay i will look into that. I am very new to programming

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you want?

```
.navDropList ul{
    margin-bottom: 15%;
    padding-left: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
```